# Laravel Trying to route the same way as Reddit does with their subreddits

Tags: php, laravel

Hello fellow Stackoverflow users,

I am currently working on a hobby-project (a Reddit clone) using Laravel.
What I am trying to achieve is to use a similar routing to posts as Reddit does.
In my case I want to navigate to a page using the current subreddit-name and ID of the post (b/subreddit-name/postId) to determine where the website has to route to. I made it work to request the ID of the post, but I couldn't manage to get it done with the current subreddit-name the user clicks on (Subbie).

By the way: Subbie's the name which I am using instead of the term "subreddit", each post has a column stored in the database with the name of the subbie, as well as the ID of the post, so it should be all retrievable.

How can I make it possible so Laravel recognizes the **"{subbie}"** variable?

(Maybe I am using the wrong words to describe my problem, but I hope it all makes sense.)

Here is the code that I am using:

*Router: web.php:*

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');

Route::get('/b/{subbie}/{id}', 'IndexController@post');
```

*Controller: IndexController.php:*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Index;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $posts = Index::all();

        return view('index', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
    public function post($id) {
        $posts = Index::findOrFail($id);

        return view('post', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
}
```

*Model: Index.php:*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Index extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

*View: index.blade.php:*

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="col-12">
            @if(count($posts) > 0)
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach ($posts as $post)
                        <a href="{!! url()->current() !!}/b/{{ $post->subbie }}/{{ $post->id }}">
                            <li class="list-group-item" style="text-decoration: none;">b/{{ $post->subbie }} · Posted by u/Test</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item" style="text-decoration: none;"><h5 class="h5">Tekst: {{ $post->body }}</h5></li>
                        </a>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @else
                <h1>Helaas zijn er nog geen artikels beschikbaar</h1>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

*View 2: post.blade.php:*

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">ID: {{ $posts->id}}</li>
</ul>
@endsection
```

Comment: You're passing two route variables to the post method. Just accept it as a parameter: post($sub, $id){} This should give you access to both.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I already tried to solve the problem like that, but I also added $subbie to the findOrFail parameters, and that was what I shouldn't have done. It works fine now, thanks.